# Set a cookie from a php dynamic variable

Tags: php, cookies

I have the below dynamic php variables.

```
responseId: <?php echo $checkAvailability->responseId?><br/>
searchId: <?php echo $checkAvailability->searchId?><br/>
totalFound: <?php echo $checkAvailability->totalFound?><br/>
```

How can i post them to the next page ? I have tried the below code but the response is empty.
1st page:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "searchID";
$cookie_value = "$checkAvailability->searchId";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
```

2nd page:

```
<?php
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[searchID];
?>
```

Could you please advise me on a safe & working method.
    - PS: i have fixed the initial issue by moving the set cookie code in the top page code.
Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get? "Undefined Index" ?

Comment: When I try your code on one page it works. Alternatively try using sessions or POST / GET to send data to other PHP scripts.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/truckass/public_html/teste.php:5) in /home/truckass/public_html/teste.php on line 8 is the line with <?php

Comment: You should not echo/print/display any data before starting sessions or setting cookies; not even a byte or the UTF-8 BOM. Check it in the data encoding page of your favourite editor.

Comment: @PeeHaa i have edit the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @PeeHaa please remove the duplicate tag as it does not have nothing to do with that question.

Comment: @PeeHaa Thanks i have found the fix for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution found:**

```
Use $_SESSION
```

Rules:On every page that you need to store/retrieve cookies put the start session code on the top of page code:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
```

On the 1st page - Page from where we store the cookie:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["searchId"] = $checkAvailability->searchId;
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>
</html>
</body>
```

On the 2nd page or on what page do you want to retrieve and use cookies :

```
<?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
<?php
//in my case i wanted to use the cookies as a php variables
$searchId = $_SESSION["searchId"];
?>
    </html>
</body>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are going to want to verify that your browser's cookies are on and what not...

Secondly, if you are going to access the cookie via $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] - then you have to make sure that $cookie_name is set to the 'searchID' value which you created the cookie with.

When I run the above code, it works just fine...

You can also do things like `print_r($_COOKIE);` to see exactly what's going on with your cookie...

But, in some cases, you may find it more appropriate to use `$_SESSION` --- Remember, the values in cookies may be tampered with...

Answer (score -1):

From manual: cookies must be sent before any output from your script

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Move setcookie code to the begin of script.